# How to give feedback on workout routines?

Tags: discussion, answers

What is the best way of giving feedback on workout routines? In most cases, there is no feedback at all from the OP to AP (Answer Post). In some cases, there is a comment in the answer. Given that most relevant feedback for Physical Fitness takes some time to be relevant, it could be a differentiator compared to answers on e.g. Superuser.

Comment: Seems like the delay between ask and answer is long enough that it doesn't really fit the SO paradigm. Personally I try to mark questions I asked so I can remember to come back and comment/accept answers weeks later after a reasonable trial period.

Comment: @Greg, when you say mark, do you mean by setting as a favorite or do you link via a document? The way I am thinking about it is that an accept means "Yes, I will try this" and maybe comeback with a comment w feedback later.

Comment: Sometimes I use favorites, or sometimes just jot down on a sticky note. Also helps to sort questions by date - newer ones are more likely to be un-accepted. As far as what an accept means, I guess that's just a personal system.